# Center vertical text

Tags: tabularx, center

I have a table and I want to have vertical centered text. But somehow my text in the table is not centered. Could you help me to center my vertical text?

```
% page setup 
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}  

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newlength\colwidth


\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\small
\settowidth\colwidth{SEThh} % set width of 1st col.
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{\colwidth}* {1}P{\colwidth}  * {5}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
& \textbf{Set}  & \textbf{category A} & \textbf{category B} &\textbf{category C} & \textbf{category D} \\
\midrule
\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Center}}} & 1.1 & Text & text &text&   - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
 \addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\endtabularx
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\addlinespace` command adds a space of 0.5 em (`\defaultaddspace=.5em`). You have seven `\addlinespace`s which add 3.5 em of extra vertical space to the 8 lines of `\multirow`. So you need to move the text down about 1.75 em (my calculation is approximate, sorry):

```
\multirow{8}{*}[-1.75em]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Center}}}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newlength\colwidth

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{table}
  \small
  \settowidth\colwidth{SEThh} % set width of 1st col.
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{\colwidth}*{1}P{\colwidth}*{5}{C}@{}}
  \toprule
   & \textbf{Set}  & \textbf{category A} & \textbf{category B} &\textbf{category C} & \textbf{category D} \\
   \midrule
   \multirow{8}{*}[-1.75em]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Center}}} 
   & 1.1 & Text & text &text&   - \\
   \addlinespace
   & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
   \addlinespace
   & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
   \addlinespace
   & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
   \addlinespace
   & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
   \addlinespace
   & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
   \addlinespace
   & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
   \addlinespace
   & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \endtabularx
 \end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: amazing! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Same reasoning, and we have to take into account the `\aboverulesep` and `belowrulesep` of the rules. By trial and error the correct value to lower the text seems to be quite close to 1.9em:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newlength\colwidth


\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\small
\settowidth\colwidth{SEThh} % set width of 1st col.
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{\colwidth}* {1}P{\colwidth} * {5}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
& \textbf{Set} & \textbf{category A} & \textbf{category B} &\textbf{category C} & \textbf{category D} \\
\midrule
\multirow{8}{*}[-1.9em]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Center}}} & 1.1 & Text & text &text& - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text& - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text& - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text& - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text& - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text& - \\
\addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text& - \\
 \addlinespace
 & 1.1 & text & text &text& - \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\endtabularx
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Text in your table is already vertical centered, so it is not entirely clear what the problem is. Vertical centering of rotated text in the first column? For it I would use `\rothead` from  the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}  % not used in this MWE
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{ Center } 
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c c  * {5}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
    & \textbf{Set}  
        & \textbf{category A} 
            & \textbf{category B} 
                &\textbf{category C} 
                    & \textbf{category D}       \\
    \midrule
\multirow{9.5}{*}{\rothead{\textbf{Center}}} 
    & 1.1 & Text & text &text&   - \\
    & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    & 1.1 & text & text &text&   - \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]